# Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined React when all properties are defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a project in React but I get that error.

I don't understand why if all properties are defined.

Anybody knows what could be happening?

The code is following. It's just a component of Numbers where the properties are: the numbers which had selected, the number selected, the numbers used and the class name of the div since I had two different classes in the  CSS.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

    export default class NumbersFrame extends Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          numbers: [],
          selectNumber: this.props.selectNumber,
          usedNumbers: this.props.usedNumbers,
          selectedNumbers: this.props.selectedNumbers,
          className: null
        }
      }


        render = () => {
          for (var i=1; i <=9; i++){
            this.setState.className = "number selected-" + (this.state.selectedNumbers.indexOf(i)>=0);
            this.setState.className = this.state.className +  " used-" + (this.state.usedNumbers.indexOf(i)>=0);
            this.state.numbers.push(
                <div className={this.state.className} onClick={this.state.selectNumber.bind(null, i)}>
                  {i}
                </div>
              )
          }

          return(
            <div id="numbers-frame">
              <div className="well">
                {this.state.numbers}
              </div>
            </div>
            );
        }
      };
```

Comment: what is the value of `this.props.selectNumber` inside the `constructor`?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be setting state that way, especially inside `render()`. Please see [Do Not Modify State Directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). Also, [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is a method that accepts arguments for en-queuing changes to the component's state.

Comment: Just a tip. you do not need to add the props properties in your state. if the parent passes new props the component will rerender so you do not need them in the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved but with a function**

I've created a function in the main wrapper component instead of a component and this works.

Anybody knows why this could be?

```
function NumbersFrame (props) {

var selectNumber = props.selectNumber,
    usedNumbers = props.usedNumbers,
    selectedNumbers =  props.selectedNumbers,
    numbers = [], 
    className = null;

  for (var i=1; i <=9; i++){
    className = "number selected-" + (selectedNumbers.indexOf(i)>=0);
    className += " used-" + (usedNumbers.indexOf(i)>=0);
    numbers.push(
        <div className={className} onClick={selectNumber.bind(null, i)}>
          {i}
        </div>
      )
     }

  return(
      <div id="numbers-frame">
        <div className="well">
          {numbers}
        </div>
      </div>
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your render method:
`render = () => {`

becomes
`render() {`

Comment: you should also not be attempting to change the state that way.

Comment: What do you suggest me to do instead?

Comment: Still getting the same error after change to render() {

Comment: Have a read of this content: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly.

But also you probably don't need state at all. Your selected numbers already comes as a prop so you could just iterate over them in the render method

`{this.props.selectedNumbers.map(selectedNumber => { ...do something })`

Comment: can you give a line number that the error occurs for? or a stack trace?

Comment: <div className={this.state.className} onClick={this.state.selectNumber.bind(null, i)}>

Comment: Then the issue is with doing .bind on `selectNumber`. `selectNumber` is either undefined when the component is initialized (i.e. there isn't a prop) or has been mutated in such a way that it has become undefined.

Comment: What do you recommend me to do to find a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps alluding to what Patrick mentioned, you should not be setting state inside of your render method.  The callback for `setState` causes your component to re-render, so it is a circular reference.  If you need to run `setState` once when the component first mounts, then you should do so inside of a different component event, such as:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState([your new state]);
}
```

Also note that `this.setState()` is a function and not a property like `this.state`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make a method like ‘setSelectedNumber(number)’ or something.

As mentioned above really bad idea to set the data in the render method. I would use the componentDidMount or componentDidReceiveProps method.

And last but not least, to update the state use:

```
this.setState({‘selectNumbers’: value});
```

If you do this in a method like i mentioned above, don’t forget to bind `this` to the method, otherwise the method will not contains a definition for `this`, so the setState method won’t be available.

To bind this to a method do this in the constructor:

```
   this.methodname = this.methodname.bind(this);
```

Gl.